# SALAR BOIS Serialization to disk

Tags: c#, serialization, disk

Can anyone tell me how to use Salar Bois serialization to disk?
I want to do the right thing since I'm optimizing both by size and time.
Specifically I had to serialize a  List lp;

All what I find on the site is:

How to serialize an object:

```
var boisSerializer = new BoisSerializer();
using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    boisSerializer.Serialize(this, mem);    
    return mem.ToArray();
}
```

How to deserialize an object:

```
var boisSerializer = new BoisSerializer();
return boisSerializer.Deserialize<SampleObject>(dataStream);
```

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: And the question is? Sorry I can't get it...

Comment: And this serialize to memory, how can I serialize to disk? There's not an overload with filename

Comment: Use FileStream instead of MemoryStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to use a `FileStream` instead of a `MemoryStream`.

There's an example at the bottom of this MSDN page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx

To use your code example however:

```
var boisSerializer = new BoisSerializer();
using (var fileStream = File.Create("c:\myfile.obj"))
{
    boisSerializer.Serialize(this, fileStream);
}
```

Clearly, your return object will change, so you'll have to account for how you're using this code.

Comment: Woah working wonder! Thanx. Comparing results with MS Binary 1/5 time 1/2 size!!!